# Java JMS to access database

Tags: java, jms

I have having this problem with Java JMS when I am sending a queue to other systems and also planning to access the database to store some pictures.

I am facing this error with the compiler:

> reference to connection is ambiguous,both interface
>   java.sql.Connection in java.sql and interface and interface javax.jms
>   Connection in javax.jms match Connection connection = null;

It should be quite a simple tweak to the code but I am not sure how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to user the fully qualified class name, that is, java.sql.Connection or javax.jms.Connection. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know which connection interface you are referring to.